# How to create an object of "unknown" class?

Tags: php, oop

I have a MySQL database and a table tobjects where each record has its `id`, `parameter`, `value` (something like XML) and one can say that this `parameter` column determines the "type" of an object.

The objects are used in some other tables, depending on their types, so each of them should be handled in specific way.

Because "handling" is somewhat common (I use the same function) I created a TObject class (not abstract but could be) from which I inherit other classes; this inheritance method is very useful and that's the very reason I use object oriented programming. For example TObject has `retrieve()` method that gets from db all the necessary data, not those in tobjects table but others too, which are type dependent, so I override it in some classes.

The problem I encountered is that when I create an object I do not know what class should it be. Of course, I can `SELECT Parameter FROM tobjects WHERE id=$id`, and then (with `switch`) create object of the proper class, and use its `retrieve()` method (each class retrieves different data, only those from tobjects are common) to get data from the db, that causes me to run query two times and some part of work outside the class, which works, but is not gentle.

The best solution would be if I can create a TObject and then, upon retrieving, change the class of the object to the one I need and it would be TObject's descendant, but I'm almost sure it's not possible.

Is my solution, that I run the first query just to select one field from tobjects only to determine object's class right? Or is there a trick to change object's class in runtime?

Comment: I'd create a factory method that indeed inspects the data (which should include your `Parameter` already) & creates the object of the type that is needed. Factory methods are your friends, especially when the codebase grows. However, a method that retrieves 'all kings of different objects' might by unmaintainable in the long run....

Comment: @Wrikken, thank you for your comment. That seems to be the only idea...

Comment: Although you [could (but should not) cast the objects at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243900/convert-cast-an-stdclass-object-to-another-class/3243949#3243949) a Factory is the most sane approach.

Comment: @Gordon, yes I knew it, thank you. Factory is ok, but I'm looping through db records (first query) and then in the factory itself once again; I thought it would be possible somehow to run query once.

Comment: @Voitcus what DB API are you using? PDO?

Comment: Does `parameter` contain the actual target class name, or just a value you allows you to determine the class name?

Comment: @DaveRandom the parameter is Integer but I get your idea - if I have string I could create object from eg. `new {'T'.$class}()`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand what you are doing correctly, here is the way I would approach this:

Passing `PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` to the first argument of `PDOStatement::fetch()` will return an object of class `PDOStatement::fetchColumn(0)` - in other words, it determines the class name to instantiate from the value of the first column of the result set.

To leverage this, you would `JOIN tobjects ON targetTable.objectType = tobjects.id` and select `tobjects.Parameter` as the first column in the result set. If the `Parameter` column already holds a 1:1 mapping of database object types to class names, this is all you need to do, however I'm not sure whether this is the case, and it probably shouldn't be, because it makes it more difficult to substitute another class at a later date.

To overcome this limitation, I suggest you create a temporary table when you first connect the database, which maps `Parameter` values to class names, which you can `JOIN` onto the query to obtain the target class name.

So the flow would go something like this:

```
// Set up the connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:yourDSNhere');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// Create a temp table to store the mapping
$db->query("
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `objectMappings` (
    `Parameter` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `ClassName` VARCHAR(255)
  ) ENGINE=MEMORY
");

// A mapping of Parameter IDs to class names
$classMap = array(
  1 => 'Class1',
  2 => 'Class2',
  3 => 'Class3',
  // ...
);

// Build a query string and insert
$rows = array();
foreach ($classMap as $paramId => $className) {
  // this data is hard-coded so it shouldn't need further sanitization
  $rows[] = "($paramId, '$className')";
}

$db->query("
  INSERT INTO `objectMappings`
    (`Parameter`, `ClassName`)
  VALUES
    ".implode(',
    ', $rows)."
");

// ...

// When you want to retrieve some data
$result = $db->query("
  SELECT m.ClassName, t.*
  FROM targetTable t
  JOIN tobjects o ON t.objectType = o.id
  JOIN objectMappings m ON o.Parameter = m.Parameter
  WHERE t.someCol = 'some value'
");

while ($obj = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE)) {
  // $obj now has the correct type, do stuff with it here
}
```

Comment: Wow! I haven't tested yet but the idea is great. I missed this `FETCH_CLASS` and `FETCH_CLASSTYPE`. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!