# PHP - Is it possible to cast to a type from a value of a string?

Tags: php

Like the title says, I want to cast to a type from the value of a string, for instance:

```
$type = "int";
$str = "20 dogs";
echo ($type)$str;
```

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, though not in the way you are showing.  There's a function for that:

```
settype($str, $type);
echo $str;
```

Also, for completeness (NOT RECOMMENDED):

```
eval("echo ($type)\$str;");
```

Comment: hmm, is it possible to cast to a specific class?

Comment: Not easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243900/convert-cast-an-stdclass-object-to-another-class