# What is the difference b/w Countable and Non Countable Objects

Tags: php, object, count, php-7.2, php-7.0

I am trying out to find difference b/w a countable and a non countable object

First I found out the Type of object

```
echo gettype($data["current_fiat_currency"]);
```

Which is a `Object`

But when i had checked that it is a countable object or not

```
var_dump($data["current_fiat_currency"] instanceof Countable );
```

then it returns

```
 False
```

Below is  the object content

```
var_dump($data["current_fiat_currency"]);

object(stdClass)[2010]
  public 'id' => string '1399' (length=4)
  public 'currency_name' => string 'US Dollar' (length=9)
  public 'currency_slug' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'currency_code' => string 'USD' (length=3)
  public 'currency_logo' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'currency_type' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 'logo' => string '.png' (length=4)
  public 'exe' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'logo_exe' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'symbol_native' => string '$' (length=1)
  public 'symbol' => string '$' (length=1)
  public 'name_plural' => string 'US dollars' (length=10)
  public 'market_cap' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'circulating_supply' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'max_supply' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'total_supply' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'cryptoid_info_exe' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'show_on_website' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'default_selected' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'exchange_rate' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'currencies_stats_exe' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'currencies_stats_last_updated' => null
  public 'mineable_or_not' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'show_on_top_bar' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'added_date' => string '2018-01-11 05:21:37' (length=19)
  public 'graph_size_chart_status' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'twitter' => null
  public 'reddit' => null
  public 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'for_pair_status' => string '0' (length=1)
```

So how i can convert a existing object to countable if it is not countable according to Php 7.2 because my codes working fine with Php 7.0.

Comment: a countable Object implements the [Interface 'Countable'](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) (which 'needs' the method 'count'), and can then be counted with the function `count($obj)`

Comment: @Jeff Please explain with example. Sorry, but I can't figure out this yet.

Comment: here's a simple example: https://3v4l.org/jas2h

Comment: this example from the docs describes it better: http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php#98303

Comment: I don't think you can 'convert' an existing stdClass Object to be a class implementing Countable. Maybe show the usecase (where you need it to be countable) to find a way around?

Comment: further read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243900/convert-cast-an-stdclass-object-to-another-class

Comment: PHP/7.2 now [warns when you `count()` a random object](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types), something that used to "work" but didn't make any sense. I wonder if that's your actual issue.

Comment: So that mean we have to implements count at every single class to make it countable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack may be

```
echo count((array) $data["current_fiat_currency"]);
```

It's just a patching solution and I think it'll work in just some cases and you should not rely on it.

Comment: We can reslove it by this way for the time being. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

An object is `Countable` when is implementing the interface `Countable`.

That interface is defining a public contract for a countable objects. That means that as part of the contract, implies that your class must implement the method `$object.count()`.

The difference is that an object that implements the `Countable interface`, means that you can execute count PHP native methods like `count()` passing as parameter your object, having as a result the value you define on the method implemented. For instance, for a non countable object you will get a *warning*.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make an object countable, it has to implement the interface `countable` and have a `count` method. I.e.

```
class YourObject implements Countable 
{

    private $whatYouWantToCount = 0;

    public function count() 
    { 
        return $this->whatYouWantToCount; 
    } 
}
```

Source http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php