# Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable codeigniter on centos

Tags: java, php, mysql, json, codeigniter

see my query

```
Select * from join_chat where
(user_1 = '24' and user_2 = '26') or
(user_1 = '26' and user_2 = '24')
```

please advice with a solution to this error from my api

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>


</div>{"responce":true,"data":"20"}
```

2020-05-09 23:16:43.302 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Select of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2020-05-09 23:16:43.302 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.302 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:163)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.302 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:176)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at util.CommonAsyTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyTask.java:104)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at util.CommonAsyTask.doInBackground(CommonAsyTask.java:23)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-05-09 23:16:43.303 28439-30249/techline.carsapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Message:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Filename: controllers/Api.php

Line Number: 801

```
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
```

The method in the controller below

```
public function send_chat_data()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('join_id', 'join_id', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sender_id', 'sender_id', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $data["responce"] = false;
        $data["error"] = 'join id is required';
    } else {
        $post_date=date("Y-m-d m:i:s");
        $send_chat = array(
                               "join_id"=>$this->input->post("join_id"),
                               "sender_id"=>$this->input->post("sender_id"),
                               "message"=>$this->input->post("message"),
                               "created_date"=>$post_date
                               );

        $this->db->insert("chat", $send_chat);
        $insertid = $this->db->insert_id();

        $q = $this->db->query("Select * from join_chat where join_id= '".$this->input->post("join_id")."' limit 1");
        $recever_id = 0;
        $row = $q->row();
        if ($row->user_1 == $this->input->post("sender_id")) {
            $recever_id = $row->user_2;
        } else {
            $recever_id = $row->user_1;
        }
        $q2 = $this->db->query("Select * from chat where chat_id= '".$insertid."' limit 1");


        $chat = $q2->row();
        $data["responce"] = true;
        $data["data"] = $chat;



        $q_fcm = $this->db->query("Select * from users where user_id= '".$recever_id."' limit 1");
        $row_fcm = $q_fcm->row();

        $registatoin_ids =$row_fcm->user_gcm_code;


        $message["title"] = $this->config->item('app_name');
        $message["message"] = $this->input->post("message");
        $message["image"] = "";
        $message["created_at"] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $message["obj"] = $chat;

        $this->load->helper('gcm_helper');
        $gcm = new GCM();
        //$result = $gcm->send_topics("/topics/rabbitapp",$message ,"ios");

        $result = $gcm->send_notification(array($registatoin_ids), $message, "android");
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

The error is from the line below

```
$row = $q->row();
```

Comment: Seems that you are trying to cast a `String` as `JSONObject`. You should parse the String as JSON first to get a JSONObject. It's hard to tell without looking at your code/implementation.

Comment: Need to see your controller implementation

Comment: I have updated the question to include the controller method causing the issue. Please Advice me on how to resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your question is as I see is that you're trying to count a non-array or non-countable object.

**Thoughts**

1. In your entire code you haven't written the `count()` which seems to
   be causing the problem, why?
2. Why do you need to count `$q->row();` when you're limiting the
   result to 1 yourself `// as you said the problem is here $row = $q->row();`

**Possible Solution**

When you use `row()` ie `$q->row();` you get a [non-countable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815632/what-is-the-difference-b-w-countable-and-non-countable-objects),

```
// row() dummy data
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 15
    [event_id] => 3
    [event_image] => c1fa8a5d5505047251fd928aa312b16c.jpg
)
```

but when you use `result()` ie `$q->result();`, it will result in an array of objects or in the case of `result_array()`, an array of arrays, even if you limit them to one.

```
// result() dummy data -- same as result_object()
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [event_id] => 3
            [event_image] => c1fa8a5d5505047251fd928aa312b16c.jpg
        )

)

// result_array() dummy data
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [event_id] => 3
            [event_image] => c1fa8a5d5505047251fd928aa312b16c.jpg
        )

)
```

Both of them are now an array and hence countable.

> So, if you must count, use **`$q->result();`**
>  Also, if you want to
>   count the number of "results" `$q->row();` has, you can use 
>   **`count((array) ($q->row()));`** 
> which will return 3 here. `{id}, {event_id}, {event_image}`. Read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Hope it helps you.