# Passing Stored Procedure result to Laravel API Resource

Tags: json, vue.js, laravel-5, stored-procedures, laravel-collection

I wanted to pass the result of the executed stored procedure to my `PB.vue`

But the problem is, it's giving me an error saying:

> Call to a member function first() on array

```
public function index()
{
    $pbs = DB::select('EXECUTE [dbo].[spQueryContainer]');

    return PBResource::collection($pbs); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB::select($query) returns an **array of stdclass** objects, not a **collection**. However, it is possible to convert it using the collect() function:

```
$pbs = DB::select('EXECUTE [dbo].[spQueryContainer]');

$pbCollection = collect($pbs); //Transform the array into a Laravel Collection of stdclass

return PBResource::collection($pbCollection);
```

Even if the Collection contains the wrong Type (stdclass instead of PB), the resource will still use it as long as the given objects have all the attributes used in your resource.

If you want a cleaner solution, you should try to convert the stdclass object to a PB object. The topic is discussed on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243900/convert-cast-an-stdclass-object-to-another-class).

Comment: Thanks, it worked but right now it showed me "undefined method stdClass::toBase()" am I still missing something to include on my controller ?

Comment: Maybe you should try converting the stdclass to PB objects. You can do this in a few steps: 1.[Convert stdClass object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array). 2.Passing the array as a constructor parameter for you PB Model ([Check this article about the $fillable property](https://lavalite.org/blog/laravel-mass-assignment-fillable-or-guarded)).

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply map the attributes from your stdClass objects to PB.